# Laravel API: extremely long timeouts for external API

Tags: laravel, rest, api

For an endpoint in the Laravel api, I am calling an external api that is extremely slow and can take 90 min to respond because it needs to run a whole bunch of processes.

In my laravel api, I am sending an immediate response to my clients that the request is launched, and they are receiving an email when the 90 min are over after I get a response from the api.

Is it ok to have timeouts of 120 minutes or even more for calling a REST API, and leaving an open connexion during all that time ? Does it affect performance for other users of my API ? Are there any Laravel parameters I need to change (except timeout) so that everything runs smoothly (e.g., is there a max number of concurrent workers ?) ?

Comment: probably want to handle this as a background queue job instead of running in the web request

Comment: Do you have a queue setup already?

Comment: and a code example would be nice :)

Comment: put code### here.

Answer (score 2):

[Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues)

If you aren't using them yet then yes you need to dispatch a job instead of just executing your code.

Step 1: Create a job

```
php artisan make:job ProcessRequest
```

Step 2: Add handle logic to job

```
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(AudioProcessor $processor)
{
    //Logic goes in here.
}
```

Step 3: Dispatch the job where needed

```
 ProcessRequest::dispatch();
```

Step 4: (Optional) Install [Laravel Horizon](https://github.com/laravel/horizon) to monitor jobs
Don't forget to start it after installing

```
php artisan horizon
```

Also take a look at [Delayed Dispatching Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#delayed-dispatching)
A good thing to have is Telescope,